# Composer php system requirements

Tags: php, composer-php

I am looking to introduce composer to an older codebase. What are the system requirements for composer? Specifically from the [docs](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#system-requirements) I see,

> Composer requires PHP 5.3.2+ to run. A few sensitive php settings and compile flags are also required, but the installer will warn you about any incompatibilities.

I would like to know what these sensitive settings and flags are? Thanks.

Comment: I want to document the requirements so that the system admin can configure the environment in production to avoid warnings. Installing locally does not warn unless there are incompatibilies, which may happen in the production box.

Comment: You can open the installer file and see which checks are made.